# could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type with long content inside of <s:select/> tag

Tags: struts2

Whenever I use a large list within the Struts2 <s:select/>, I get the following error:
["could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type" Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQncN.png)

This does not work:

```
<s:select name="state" label="State" list="#{'AL':'Alabama', 'AK':'Alaska', 'AZ':'Arizona', 'AR':'Arkansas', 'CA':'California', 'CO':'Colorado', 'CT':'Connecticut', 'DE':'Delaware', 'FL':'Florida', 'GA':'Georgia', 'HI':'Hawaii', 'ID':'Idaho', 'IL':'Illinois', 'IN':'Indiana', 'IA':'Iowa', 'KS':'Kansas', 'KY':'Kentucky', 'LA':'Louisiana', 'ME':'Maine', 'MD':'Maryland', 'MA':'Massachusetts', 'MI':'Michigan', 'MN':'Minnesota', 'MS':'Mississippi', 'MO':'Missouri', 'MT':'Montana', 'NE':'Nebraska', 'NV':'Nevada', 'NH':'New Hampshire', 'NJ':'New Jersey', 'NM':'New Mexico', 'NY':'New York', 'NC':'North Carolina', 'ND':'North Dakota', 'OH':'Ohio', 'OK':'Oklahoma', 'OR':'Oregon', 'PA':'Pennsylvania', 'RI':'Rhode Island', 'SC':'South Carolina', 'SD':'South Dakota', 'TN':'Tennessee', 'TX':'Texas', 'UT':'Utah', 'VT':'Vermont', 'VA':'Virginia', 'WA':'Washington', 'WV':'West Virginia', 'WI':'Wisconsin', 'WY':'Wyoming', 'AS':'American Samoa', 'DC':'District of Columbia', 'FM':'Federated States of Micronesia', 'GU':'Guam', 'MH':'Marshall Islands', 'MP':'Northern Mariana Islands', 'PW':'Palau', 'PR':'Puerto Rico', 'VI':'Virgin Islands'}" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select State --" />
```

vs.

This works:

```
                <s:select name="state" label="State" list="#{'CA':'California', 'NY':'New York', 'TX':'Texas'}" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select State --" requiredLabel="true"/>
```